# uploading files via GUI and selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I'm having trouble uploading a file into a website. I've tried using the following code and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(x_path).send_keys(full/path/of/file)
```

The next step would be to interact directly with the GUI below but I have no idea how to even begin doing so. 
Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Update your question with HTML. Do you have any errors?

Comment: what is `x_path`? Why are you trying to interact with the GUI instead of using the `Choose File` keyword?

Comment: Can you share more of the actual test code you've tried?